# How to send multiple request in nodejs using ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm getting data through a single request. But here I am trying to send multiple HTTP requests. Here I just struck unable to get data and how to pass data in view page i.e, in  EJS

```
router.get('/specials',function(req,res,next){
    var callbackThree = function(error, resp, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
      res.render("specials",{ data: data});
  }

  var callbackTwo = function(error, resp, body) {
    request("https://siteblabla.com/wsmenu/sub_menu_list/789/", callBackThree);
  }

  var callbackOne = function(error, resp, body) {
    request("https://siteblabla.com/wsspecials/specials_list/123/", callBackTwo);
  }
//  request("api.com/users", callBackOne);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Promises` and there is a great `npm` package called **ejs-promise** which you can make use of in your case.

You can download it at the below URL,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-promise

Hope this helps!